# RSPEC: Random number expectation

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am very new to RSPEC and Ruby How do I create a test that will pass if the number is between 0 and 36?

Thanks in advance.

```
describe "Roulette" do
    context "Randomiser:" do
        it 'randomises a number between 0 and 36'
            expect(randomiser).to eq XXXX
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple.

```
expect(randomiser).to be > 0 
expect(randomiser).to be < 36
```

or

```
randomiser.should be > 0
randomiser.should be < 36
```

Cheers, humbroll.

Answer (score 0):

Since roulette wheels include 36 and a house number, here's a contrived example:

```
describe "Roulette" do
  it 'randomizes a number between 0 and 36' do
    num = Random.new
    r_num = num.rand(36)
    r_num.should be >= 0
    r_num.should be <= 36
  end
end
```